# Will Xcode warn me if I use API's not availble to iOS Deployment Target?

Tags: ios, xcode

When developing an app using Xcode 9, I am able to specify a deployment target as old as iOS 8.0 `[Select Project] > [Select Target] > Build Settings > Deployment iOS Deployment Target`:

[image: Deployment Target List]

If I select this before writing my app, will Xcode warn me if I use an API that's not supported in the older versions of iOS?

If I were well-versed in using Xcode, I certainly wouldn't need to ask this question since I would have naturally have encountered an API version situation.   But since I have no experience with coding in this domain, I also have no experience with which API's were added, and when, so don't have enough information to experiment.

Comment: Try it. What happens?

Comment: "Trying it" would require me to know what API's to try.  I don't have any history with programming in this domain, so don't know how to "try it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You will receive a compiler error "'api' is only available on IOS XX or newer".
The compiler will also give you options to automatically add in code to check if the api is available and use it if it is. So you can fall back if the api is not there and use it if it is. An example of this generated code is below.

`if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            safeArea = self.view.safeAreaInsets
    }`